# Math Quiz question $(5b^4)^2$

Tags: exponential-sum

So in this question, I got $25b^8$, though my teacher marked it wrong and said it was $5b^8$, he said don't multiply the bases. But $5$ is not the base, $b$ is the base and $5$ is the coefficient. I am confused, I checked my word in a calculator and got $25b^8$. Help please

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Comment: I would say that $(5b^4)^2$ is definitely equal to $25 b^8$ ...

Comment: Yeah so my teacher is wrong?

Comment: It all hangs on where the left bracket was in the problem. If it was, as you say, $(5b^4)^2$ then you are right. If it was $5(b^4)^2$, then your teacher is right.

Comment: Thanks everyone

Comment: The answer is definitely $25b^8$. This kind of thing really bothers me. How can a teacher make a mistake like this? I'd like to know the resolution to this Jason if you get an update from the teacher.

Comment: I am almost sure that your exercise was $5(b^4)^2$. If not, change teacher ASAP!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jason. Welcome to StackExchange! First, thanks for following the guidelines on posting your problem (i.e. explain the problem and show your work).

I would argue that *you* are correct (my background is a BS, almost MS in math and candidacy for a BSE in Secondary Education Mathematics). Here's why:

Do you recall the term *monomial*? By definition, this is a one-term polynomial (it just has a variable raised to a power and a coefficient).

In our case, our monomial is $(5b^4)^2$. Since this monomial is raised to the second power, we interpret this as $5b^4\cdot5b^4=(5\cdot5)\cdot(b^4\cdot b^4)=25\cdot b^{4+4}=25\cdot b^8=25b^8$.

[This](https://sciencing.com/negative-exponents-rules-for-multiplying-dividing-13712457.html) website further explains how to solve problems of this nature should the teacher refuse both of our explanations. (If your teacher argues these are not of the form (coefficient$\cdot$variable$^{power}$)$^{power}$, then remind them you can rewrite it as I did. Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you so much everybody! Yeah, this isn't the first mistake he made, I am thinking about what I should do from this point on. I appreciate all your help!